# xhr failed loading: post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //peticion ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/inicioDeSesion.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (respoonse == 1) {
                    window.locatio="../inicio/index.php";
                }else{
                    $("#alertalogin").text(response);
                }
            }
        });

       return false;
     });
```

//codigo php

```
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['contrasena'])) {


$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['contrasena'];

$rt = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' and contrasena = '$password' ";
$tg = mysqli_query($conexion, $rt);
$a = mysqli_fetch_array($tg);


if ($usuario = $a['usuario'] && $password = $a['contrasena']) {
     echo 1;

     $_SESSION['id_use'] = $a['id_use'];
     $_SESSION['nombre'] = $a['nombre'];
     $_SESSION['apellido'] = $a['apellido'];
     $_SESSION['usuario'] = $a['usuario'];
     $_SESSION['email'] = $a['email'];
     $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $a['contrasena'];
     $_SESSION['fecha_reg'] = $a['fecha_reg'];
}else {
    echo '*El usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.'
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Conviene siempre explicar un poco lo que intentas hacer. En tu código hay errores de lógica y de sintaxis. 1. Corrige esto: **`window.location="../inicio/index.php";`** luego, si la respuesta espera un JSON tienes que crear un array con la respuesta y buscar el valor por el nombre de su clave o bien cambiar el tipo de respuesta a `html`

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, lo que me indicas a corregir fue un error mio al escribirlo aqui, en mi codigo esta bien, pude solucionar el problema y el error estaba en la url de ajax: *url: 'aqui tuve que indicar la url del archivo php',*

Comment: Ok, Como quiera hace falta dar coherencia al código, emitiendo una respuesta del tipo que indicaste en `dataType`. Estás emitiendo HTML y deberías emitir un JSON, o podrías tener problemas del tipo JSON parse.